# Disabling AutoCompleteType property on asp.net textbox not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a program where you can enter Customer Informations like Names, addresses and many other sensitive data. I would like to disable the textbox in remembering the last entered values for data privacy security. I tried setting properties of the textbox like EnableViewState="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" but it does not work. This  is my line of code

<asp:TextBox ID="txt_umuna" runat="server" Width="424px" placeholder="First Name" EnableViewState="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="nope"></asp:TextBox>

I notice that the property actually works when I change the placeholder value into any kind of string that does not contain any indication that it is a field that accepts name. I tried removing the placeholder and just added a text beside it like First Name: then the textbox. but the same thing happened. It seems that the browser automatically detects that the textbox is for entering Names of the encoder and automatically gets data from Personal Info History of the browser as an option or the autocomplete selections. Do you have any solutions for this? Helps will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your issue may be from the browser and not the ASP.NET server code. What type of browser are you using? Have you tried to disable the autocomplete features on your browser?

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply Sir. I did try disabling the autocomplete features of the browser and it worked. However, is there any way I can fix this programmatically?, without relying on the browser and disable the feature first? My problem here is that I think browsers autocomplete features are turned on by default. So, most customers might have their personal info exposed on the browser if not turned off manually.

Comment: I am not aware of a way for a web server to instruct the browser to disable or enable autocomplete. But perhaps others will submit answers to your question about this.